# Handling data inside dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one problem with one of my projects at school. I am attempting to change the order of my data. 
You are able to appreciate how the data is arranged 
[this picture contains a sample of the data I am referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NZzv.png)

This is the format I am attempting to reach:

```
Company name | activity description | year | variable 1 | variable 2 |......
company 1    |                      | 2011 |            |            |
company 1    |                      | 2012 |            |            | 
..... (one row for every year ( from 2014 to 2015 inclusive))
company 2    |                      | 2011 |            |            |
company 2    |                      | 2012 |            |            |    
..... (one row for every year ( from 2014 to 2015 inclusive))
```

for ever single one of the 10 companies. this is a sample of my whole data-set, which contains more than 15000 companies. I attempted creating a dataframe of the size I want but I have problems filling it with the data I want and in the format I want. I am fairly new to python. Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the problem is you're trying to solve. You already have a dataframe with data, what isn't working exactly?

Comment: please stop to put image, put data to help us rebuild dataframe..

Comment: [Please don't upload images of code/data on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: you have to create a sample dataframe which represents your data and an expected output briefly describing all changes you wanna make. Else all of us will just guess and the chain will go on forever